# what are the limit factors in number of simultaneous running pods in GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have 3 nodes on n1-standard-16 with pods that require around 1.2 CPU + 0.2 overhead = 1.4 CPU. Theoretically, I should be able to schedule more than 30 pods among the three. However, the moment they get created, they will get terminated (immediately). I could easily see this by increasing the replicas. The number of pods that always remain is 10, regardless of what I pick for the replica parameter (anything between 10 - 30 gives me 10 | below 10 of course gives me below 10 pods). Even while 10 were running I checked the nodes and they all had ton of room to accept more pods.

The first place I looked into were the quotas (CPU and IP were close but nowhere near the limits), everything was fine. I also looked into the kubectl describe pods pod-name file of the pod just before the termination, nothing out of ordinary. The last few lines are:

```
  Normal   Created    21s   kubelet  Created container X
  Normal   Started    20s   kubelet  Started container X
  Normal   Pulled     20s   kubelet  Container image Z already present on machine
  Normal   Created    20s   kubelet  Created container Y
  Normal   Started    20s   kubelet  Started container Y
  Normal   Killing    15s   kubelet  Stopping container X
  Normal   Killing    15s   kubelet  Stopping container Y
  Warning  Unhealthy  11s   kubelet  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500
```

My question is why GKE can schedule my pods and run the containers but immediately stopping them?

1. CPU and Memory: Checked - That is not the case for my scenario
2. Quota limitations: Checked - That is not the case for my scenario
3. Pod logs: Checked - Nothing informative
4. ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have edited the following flag, [--max-pods-per-node](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/flexible-pod-cidr?_ga=2.209983509.-1631918676.1594306353&_gac=1.243057334.1600217636.EAIaIQobChMIlLWklrvs6wIVXPzjBx2kiACyEAAYASAAEgIOufD_BwE#creating_a_cluster_with_a_maximum_of_8_pods_per_node) when creating your cluster/node pool?

Comment: Thank you Dany! I don't have such config (--max-pods-per-node) in my deployment yml file nor did I declare it when creating my node-pools. Where can check the current value set for --max-pods-per-node?

Comment: I ran kubectl describe nodes My-Node | grep -i pods and it shows 110, so most likely that is not the issue.

Comment: 110 is default value, so my guess was wrong. "-max-pods-per-node" could have been a limiting factor. Other than that maybe ip space however, errors are pointing towards that.

Comment: Perhaps if you do a kubectl describe pods [affected_pod_name], you will get more info.

Comment: Are you referring to "In-use IP addresses"? because as far as I understand, each node takes one IP and if all of my 3 nodes can live forever, it already passed the IP restrictions (also I can see that I haven't passed my quota). However, if there is another type of IP that is somehow related to pods, then please let me know of what I should search for and I can dig deeper.

Comment: Edit: i meant,  errors are not pointing towards that at this point.

Comment: Try to turn autoscaler on for your nodepool. This should give us more information.

Comment: I ran kubectl describe pods [affected_pod_name], Only the last lines that I included in the question were odd.